# Lazy Exception with TransactionAttribute as not supported

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb

I'm getting some issues with lazy initialization in a project I've been working in. Sometimes I'm consulting my database using `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)`, which usually works fine, except when I try to initialize dependent entities.

These dependent entities are which are all annotated with "`fetch = FetchType.LAZY`" (they have to be) and I try to get them using Hibernate.initialize(something);. When I do so, I get org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session.

I tried to use `<property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true">` in my persistence.xml but got no success (it's like I didn't do anything).

Do you guys have any idea of why do I have to have a transaction opened just to bring information from my data source and if is there any way to do it all keeping my the transaction attribute as not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the same view for the entity and its relations the relation must be loaded in the same transaction IIRC.
So if you have a Bean without a Tx the persistence is not able to guarantee the consistency.